How to Link (Simple)Perf Events for ARM CPUs on Android with Concise Metric Description?
Where can I get detailed information about (simple)perf events for ARM CPUs on Android?
simpleperf list specifies many metrics to track:
simpleperf list                                                                                                                                                                     
List of hw-cache events:
  # More cache events are available in `simpleperf list raw`.
  branch-load-misses
  branch-loads
  dTLB-load-misses
  dTLB-loads
  iTLB-load-misses
  iTLB-loads
  L1-dcache-load-misses
...

For many metrics, I can guess what they mean, but there must be an authoritative source describing the metrics briefly. For Intel processors, I find https://perfmon-events.intel.com/ very helpful.
To make the question more concrete, consider the following output:
Performance counter statistics:

#          count  event_name              # count / runtime
  14,318,501,812  L1-dcache-loads         # 1.620 G/sec  
  10,143,409,943  raw-mem-access          # 1.491 G/sec  


What does raw-mem-access mean? What do I need to do to link it to a short description in some ARM publication?
I grepped through the source code of simple-perf and read the documentation, but I couldn't figure out how to map metrics denoted by simpleperf to ARM's performance events and what they mean. Simpleperf recommends:

Please refer to "PMU common architectural and microarchitectural event numbers" and "ARM recommendations for IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED event numbers" listed in ARMv8 manual for details. A possible link is https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0487/latest/arm-architecture-reference-manual-armv8-for-armv8-a-architecture-profile.

but that didn't bring me very far either.
